Excel: sum values in a column that match values in another column
I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

I need in the row Total of the first table the sum of the Working Hours as they are set in the second table (on the right) based on the Schedule.
So for Luca, the total it's gonna be 38, For Alessandro 36.
I've tried with LOOKUP, SUMPRODUCT and many more, the thing is that I'm not able to work with excel, so I don't even know how to debug some function asked to ChatGPT (that of course are not working).
Thanks for your help!

Just use SUMPRODUCT to sum up the occurrences of each turn multiplied by hours:

Formula in cell B12:
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B2:B8;$F$2:$F$5)*$H$2:$H$5)

This is how it works:

COUNTIF(B2:B8;$F$2:$F$5) will return an array based on your input in cells F2:F5 counting how many times each word is matched. For Luca this array will be 1/4/1/1. That means 1 Morning, 4 After, 1 Both, 1 Rest.
COUNTIF(B2:B8;$F$2:$F$5)*$H$2:$H$5 We multiply the array 1/4/1/1 with their hours in array format, that means 1/4/1/1 * 6/6/8/0 = 6/24/8/0
Because we are using arrays we trap all inside SUMPRODUCT to sum up each value of the final array so 6/24/8/0 becomes 6 + 24 + 8 + 0 = 38

